# Enable eureka.client.healthcheck

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm following http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html to build distributed system with Spring Cloud.

All works as expected apart from Eureka Client Healthcheck.

I have

eureka:
  client:
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true

And pointing my service to nonexisten config_server, this results in

http://myservice:8080/health
{
status: "DOWN"
}

But Eureka server still showing this instance as UP and keep sending traffic to it.

What am I missing?

spring-boot: 1.2.8.RELEASE

spring-cloud-netflix : 1.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: Please, attach the used Spring cloud version too. BTW, eureka sometimes takes a time to notice a service is down (that depends on how your services send heartbeats to it). Have you tried waiting for a while?

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly set `eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true` to link the Spring Boot health indicator to the Eureka registration. Source code reference: [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/82991a7fc2859b6345b7f67e2461dbf5d7663836/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.java#L207).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I found it.

According to https://jmnarloch.wordpress.com/2015/09/02/spring-cloud-fixing-eureka-application-status/ this feature will only be available on Spring Cloud 1.1.

To make it work with 1.0.4 I need to implement my own HealthCheckHandler.

Thanks @xtreme-biker for bringing up Spring Cloud version issue.

Comment: You're welcome. Next time take care about the versions you're using, check docs for the exact versions and, if any problem, provide the numbers in the question as it's always relevant.